# How to validate if a record exists in Sql with JQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, customvalidator

i have an app and when i write a number in a textbox,i have to check if this number exists in database or not.How can i do that with Custom Validator and JQuery Ajax functions ? Thank you so much in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Have you already got a handler set up for ajax (.ascx, .asmx, .aspx file?). You need to help us to help you.

Comment: this can be done but you need to use some sort of server side language such as php, asp.net etc. to connect to the database and find out the information you need and then to pass the result back to your original page via ajax.

Comment: @martincarlin87 i used asp.net.i wrote a webservice that is returning a boolean value.as you said,i coulndt pass the result back to original page.What is the exact ajax syntax ?

Comment: @ErdemGundogdu http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ The key bit is in the `success()` function, whatever data is returned, you can do this to see it and then take it from there: `success: function(response) { alert(response);}` I would also recommend using Firefox and the Firebug add on and that way you can see the requests in terms of the parameters that are sent and also what is returned and if they were successful or not. Hope that helps.

Comment: @martincarlin87 thank you,all im looking for is "function(response)" . I guess i can decide what to do with 'response' .'response' is the result from the webservice function, isnt it ? thank you so much

Comment: @ErdemGundogdu yep, it's known as the callback function. the `response` variable is what is returned from your server-side processing script. In your case you could set the background colour of the text box to green or red depending on if response is equal to 1 or 0 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not write a JavaScript to connect to SQL.

1. write a function in your js to ajax post your textbox value to a server side validation method.
2. Serverside validation method check given value with your database
   and return true or false.
3. validation function in your js reflect properly with your ajax post
   results on success.

References to study: 
1. api.jquery.com: look for $.post

Comment: There's lots of ajax validators with good documentations. Just search jQuery validation plugin.